# Internal Server Error when deploying simple Flask app onto GCloud

Tags: python, flask, google-app-engine

When I run this app locally, it works fine. In the cloud, I get the error below. I think it's my yaml file. As a side note, if there is anything in the logs I should not be sharing, I'd appreciate knowing. Thank you!

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

My **main.py** file:

```
from flask import Flask
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def data():
    response = requests.request("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
    data = response.json()
    return(data)

returned_data = data()

#for i, item in enumerate(returned_data):

#    userID = item.get("userID", None)
#    id = item.get("id", None)
#    title = item.get("id", None)

#    print(userID,id,title)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

My **app.yaml** file:

```
runtime: python39
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT -w 2 main:app
```

My **app.yaml** file:

```
runtime: python39
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT -w 2 main:app
```

and my requirements.txt

```
requests
Flask==2.1.0
gunicorn
```

Here are the logs:

```
{
insertId: "63604ebd000c8d09af3f2e13"
labels: {
clone_id: "00c61b114F0e8fb053d8ebee071db45f9aa9ec947906c0029f3b30b22f414ae90868c30c989456619d667de0e08ca37e2598be2ed37ad5d3b"
}
logName: "projects/XXXX/logs/%2Fvar%2Flog%2Fgoogle_init.log"
receiveTimestamp: "2022-10-31T22:39:58.016186551Z"
resource: {
labels: {
module_id: "default"
project_id: "XXXX"
version_id: "20221031t161907"
zone: "us6"
}
type: "gae_app"
}
textPayload: "[start] 2022/10/31 22:39:57.821966 Start program failed: termination triggered by nginx exit"
timestamp: "2022-10-31T22:39:57.822537Z"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is producing a list and trying to return a list as you're doing in flask will lead to the error -

`TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a list.`

To fix the error, modify your code to use `jsonify`

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def data():
    response = requests.request("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
    data = response.json()
    # return(data)
    return jsonify(data) # New; jsonify the list before it's returned

#returned_data = data() This line also causes an error
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain to me why it works as is in my local server but not in google cloud? I appreciate it!

Comment: I don't know how you're running the code locally. If you'd run it with ```dev_appserver.py```, you should have received the error I posted. I also believe you'll get the same output using ```flask run``` Maybe the way you've run it locally has set the appropriate headers (which is what Jsonify does).

Comment: With at least some versions of Flask, when you return a dict, it is automatically jsonified so that you don't need to do it yourself.